# Voltage without amps

Tags: energy

I have just read an article on electricity extracted from the atmosphere. Apparently there is a massive supply of collectible voltage available from the air. However the amps available is very low.

My question is, is there any way excessive voltage can be converted to amps so that extracting electricity from the atmosphere could become a new source of free energy?

Comment: There is no free lunch. Look up the laws of thermodynamics.

Comment: ... and lightning discharge.

Comment: "I just read an article" Which article? Link, if possible. There's a lot of what us experts call "*bullshit*" online about getting energy. "Massive supply of collectible voltage": Voltage isn't "collectible".

Answer (score 1):

Your idea of volts without amps as useful energy is something beyond all science and engineering. If I were able to write something which supports the main title idea my account would be soon terminated. But I try to write something which is acceptable in this site

As already commented, there's much free energy bullshit. But in reality the wind can make plenty of work. Some of that work is unwanted (storms, lightning). Windmills and sailing are popular ways to get that work under some control.

In principle the same mechanism which creates lightning could also generate electricity in a controlled way. The wind could be the moving part in an electrostatic generator. See this article of of what's that kind of generator: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrostatic_generator

Static electricity means that molecule structure differences of different materials make possible that some electrons jump from one material to another when different materials rub each other. In lightning clouds the different materials are believed to be different crystal forms of freezed water. Heavier crystals fall down and the lighter ones with opposite charge stay in the air, so substantial charges can get accumulated.

Thus it's well possible that constantly blowing wind can give or catch electrons from a piece of solid material and substantial amount of charge could be generated to a wanted place. For continuous operation there of course should be a closed circuit through a load. I have seen one patent of that: https://patents.google.com/patent/US4433248. It inserts water droplets to the airstream to enhance the conversion.

BTW those already common gigantic windmill turbine generators get rubbed by the wind when they do their work. In theory someone could find a way to catch some energy also from it as an efficiency boost. At least the mechanism and electric wires are already there. I am not able to do any calculations of the amount of the available static electricity and how that side operation interacts with the main operation.